# Apache virtual proxy, do not redirect from root

Tags: apache, jenkins, continuous-integration, mod-proxy

I have the following in my vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ci.myserver.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I visit my root (myserver.com) I get my Jenkins, as well as when I visit ci.myserver.com

How to I get not redirected to CI  when I visit myserver.com, but only make it work for ci.myserver.com

*Updated version*

This resolved an issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ci.myserver.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another `VirtualHost`, otherwise hostnames that resolve the ip of your server will hit the default `VirtualHost`, which in your case is `ci.myserver.com`.

Add another to the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/root

    <Directory /path/to/root>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks it did help! could you please review my updated version to see for any possible security issues?

Comment: Well I certainly wouldn't set your document root to `/` but I don't know if you've only done that for the purposes of illustrating your config.